# No puedo obtener un parametro de una Funcion void

Tags: java

Me gustaria obtener Coorxcen , le eh dado return Coorxcen , pero me sale error de que es una funcion void , como podria obtener Coorxcen ?

```
public LadriMoviEntity(World world, Texture pared, float CoorXcen, float CoorYcen){
    this.world= world;
    this.texture= pared;
    float mediBase=1.5f;// la mediBase es la mitad del objeto
    float mediAltu=0.3f;
    BodyDef def= new BodyDef();
    def.position.set(CoorXcen,CoorYcen);// posicion tomando en cuenta el punto medio
    def.type=BodyDef.BodyType.KinematicBody;// es estatico el objeto
    body = world.createBody(def);

    PolygonShape rectangulo= new PolygonShape();
    rectangulo.setAsBox(mediBase, mediAltu); // tamaño de espiritu , esto se multiplica por 2
    fixture= body.createFixture(rectangulo, 1);
    fixture.setUserData("piso");
    rectangulo.dispose();

    setSize(3 * PIXELS_IN_METER, 0.6f * PIXELS_IN_METER);// tamaño real

    return CoorXcen;
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Asumiendo que `LadriMoviEntity` no es constructor de clase usted puede especificar el tipo de retorno en este caso float, puede ver este ejemplo:

```
public float LadriMoviEntity(World world, Texture pared, float CoorXcen, float CoorYcen){

    ..//
    return CoorXcen;
}
```

---

> Si , eso use ... El return Coorxcen , pero me marca como si fuera de
>   un void .... Y quisiera extraer ese parametro

no entiendo muy bien el comentario pero intentare aclara algo mas la respuseta:

Si quieres obtener algun tipo de retorno tiene que indicar el que quieras, en este caso es float asi que añadimos:

```
public float   <--- añades float que es el tipo de retorno
```

y tambien añades el return:

```
return CoorXcen; <--- añades return
```

podrias usarlo de esta manera por ejemplo, en alguna parte de tu codigo:

```
..//
float coor_x_cen = tuObjeto.LadriMoviEntity(...); //si usas un objeto.
..//
```

Por otro lado no se muy bien lo que quieres hacer con Box2d, ni tampoco me has dicho si `LadriMoviEntity` es el constructor de clase, pero dices que quieres `Coorxcen` pero usted lo tiene al momento de llamar a `LadriMoviEntity` pues se lo pasas como parametro y este no se modifica en ningun momento asi que, como mismo lo pasas lo puedes usar desde donde llamas `LadriMoviEntity` sin tener que usar el return pues no se modifica.

Pero si `LadriMoviEntity` es constructor de clase usted pude crear algun get y set para consultar ese valor por ejemplo algo asi:

```
float coorXcen;

public LadriMoviEntity(World world, Texture pared, float CoorXcen, float CoorYcen){

    ..//
    this.coorXcen = CoorXcen;        
}

public float getCoorXcen(){
   return this.coorXcen;
}
```

en otra parte de su codigo donde tenga acceso al objeto y quiera usarlo:

```
..//
float coor_x_cen = tuObjeto.getCoorXcen(); //si usas un objeto.
..//
```

Comment: Eso es lo que hago el return , pero me sale que no es posible hacer un return de una funcion void, no se si abra otra forma como podria sacar ese valor de CoorXcen de esa funcion

Comment: @HansLeoQuirozMarroquin LadriMoviEntity es el constructor de clase?

Comment: float coorXcen;

{
this.coorxcen= CoorXcen;

Con este me salio , muchas gracias :)  no sé como etiketarlos :s , pero gracias a todos :)